Pandas: How to get 0 count for all items in a column not matching a query
I will give a simple dataframe as an example:



ID
Year
Company
Product




1
1984
ACME
P1


2
1986
ACME
P2


7
1959
ACME
P7


3
1951
SMITH
P3


4
1982
COLEMAN
P4


5
1987
HILL
P5


6
1960
TANNER
P6



If I wanted to get a count of all product years 1980 or later, reporting those companies with entries only before 1980 as 0, how would I do it?
If I filter on YEAR >= 1980 then try to get the counts from that, then I would likely get ACME:2, COLEMAN:1, HILL:1.
What I would want though is ACME:2, COLEMAN:1, HILL:1, SMITH:0, TANNER:0.  I would not want to count the ACME row before 1980

You can turn the year into a boolean column and groupby.sum:
df['Year'].gt(1980).groupby(df['Company']).sum()

Output:
Company
ACME       2
COLEMAN    1
HILL       1
SMITH      0
TANNER     0
Name: Year, dtype: int64


Do a groupby and sum:
import io

import pandas as pd

with io.StringIO('''ID  Year    Company     Product
1   1984    ACME    P1
2   1986    ACME    P2
7   1959    ACME    P7
3   1951    SMITH   P3
4   1982    COLEMAN     P4
5   1987    HILL    P5
6   1960    TANNER  P6
''') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(
        f,
        delim_whitespace=True,
    ).set_index(['Company', 'ID'])

counts = (
    df['Year'] >= 1980
).groupby('Company').sum()
print(counts)

Company
ACME       2
COLEMAN    1
HILL       1
SMITH      0
TANNER     0
Name: Year, dtype: int64

